# What statistical test do you perform to compare sugar consumption between two groups of people?

Tags: biostatistics

I collected data from 10 patients regarding the amount of sugar they consume in a day and want to see whether this amount significantly differs from the average amount of sugar consumed by the general population per day.

This value consumed by the general population is a single average value published by a national institute. Is it possible to compare multiple values of the patient group with a single value of the general population? What test should I perform and how do I do it? I am familiar with PSPP. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could perform a `t-test` with the hypothesis set as $$H_0:\mu = \mu_0\\H_1: \mu\neq \mu_0$$ where $\mu_0$ is the average published by the national institution.

In R, you could use the function `t.test` as shown below:

```
x <- rnorm(10, 39, 2) #just generating random data ie grams/day
t.test(x, mu = 35) #comparing to the published value 35
```